# Баг prefab'a в unity(2D)

Tags: unity3d

У меня есть 3 префаба (бомбы которые падают на персонажа. Префабы с триггером). Если этот префаб упадет на игрока, то у игрока отнимутся жизни, но когда бомба падает, жизни не отнимаются, только после выключение игры в самой unity они уже меняется (то есть когда игра выключена жизни изменяются)

Это скрипт триггера

```
public class TriggerDelete : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject obj;

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
    {
        if (col.tag == "Trigger")
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }

        if (col.tag == "Player")
        {
            obj.GetComponent<Health>().health -= 50;



        }

    }

}
```

Скрипт здоровье

```
public class Health : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float health;

    public GameObject die;
    public GameObject normal;

    void Update()
    {
        if (health <= 0)
        {

            normal.SetActive(false);
            die.SetActive(true);
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. Прошу меня простить, т.к. unity я изучаю только 2 недели и мог написать не то что понял!

Comment: Может так и должно быть?

Comment: Покажите хотя бы ваш скрипт

Comment: Да, уже отправил!

Comment: На кого висит скрипт `TriggerDelete`?

Comment: Скрипт TriggerDelete висит на бомбу. Он изначально висел на другом объекте, но я забыл поменять названия

Comment: Попробуйте [этот](https://github.com/Eccs0103/Share/blob/master/Health.cs) код вместо вашего в скрипте `Health`, а [этот](https://github.com/Eccs0103/Share/blob/master/TriggerDelete.cs) вместо `TriggerDelete`

Comment: Ошибка исправилась?

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте что `Collider` вашего `Player` имеет включенный `IsTrigger`, необходимый тег, и есть ли компонент `Rigidbody2D`на одном из объектов

Проверьте что Вы видите изменения здоровья, проследите за изменениями здоровья возможно Вы можете упустить моменты когда Вы теряете здоровье.

Вариант с багом **префаба** кажется абсурдным, объект находится на сцене и будет меняться так Вы задаёте.

Comment: Получается у меня "IsTrigger" весит на самих бомбах и они определяет куда они упали (На них и весит Rigidbody2D). Если бомба упала на объект с тэгом "Player", то скрипт "TriggerDelete" находит скрипт объект по переменной "obj", на объекте он находит скрипт "Health", потом в скрипте  "Health", он ищет переменную "health" и отнимает 50, но сам скрипт "TriggerDelete" отнимает здоровье после завершения игры. Я думаю это из-за того что бомба и скрипт "TriggerDelete" находятся в прифабе и обновляется после завершение игры. Можно ли это исправить? Надеюсь более понятно объяснил)

Comment: @Nikita как Вы понимаете что обновляется после завершения игры? Подскажите как следите за процессом отнимания здоровья

Comment: Я запускаю игру в unity, на меня падает бомба, здоровье не отнимается, закрываю игру в редакторе, здоровье обновляется

Answer (score 0):

Возможно стоит проверить висит ли скрипт TriggerDelete на активном объекте.

Скрипты на неактивных объектах не выполняют свою реализацию.